# windows server 2008 firewall, possible to backup settings?

Tags: windows-server-2008

Is it possible to backup the windows server 2008 firewall settings?

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Configure-Windows-2008-Advanced-Firewall-NETSH-CLI.html

Export

Lets you export all the current configurations of your firewall to a file. This command is very helpful because you can back up all your settings to file and restore them if you don’t like the configurations that you have made.

Here is an example:

netsh advfirewall export “c:\advfirewall.wfw”